# How do I set the image mode to 4-bit grayscale (16-color)? Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, grayscale

I see I can adjust my image between 8, 16, and 32 bits per channel, and when I create a new image I can choose between bitmap (1-bit) or 16-bit+ in all the other modes.

Is there a way to do a 4-bit mode? I'm trying to do some image editing for some e-ink displays (16-color grayscale, aka 4-bit) but I cannot for the life of me figure this out in Photoshop CS6, and most google results are just 'how to make an image greyscale'.

Alternatively, what software could I use to create and edit images in a 4-bit grayscale mode?

Comment: The mode is called indexed

Answer (score 1):

I have a suggestion, but i don't know is it what you want or not.

1. Make Image Grayscale (Image-> Mode-> Grayscale)
2. Press Alt + Shift + Ctrl + S
3. Change the values as following image
   [image]
4. Finally press save button

this will save your image as a gif image.
you can open it in Photoshop again and save it as a jpg file. but I dont know does it work for your purpose or not!!!